# Bass' formula (homological algebra)

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I am studying homological algebra and I want to be familiar with Bass' formula which associate the injective dimension to the depth of module and ring. I am looking for an online version and I can not find the statement or the proof of it! I was wondering if someone could help me.

Comment: is this helpful? http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0312513.pdf

Comment: Yes , the statement is in it!